# Unable to fix - unmet dependencies and low file system root space

Tags: files, root, system

I am trying to update my system (Ununtu 14.04) but Ubuntu tells me that I have not enough space on file system root (although it is 20GB). I searched for it and tried many suggestion including autoremove, autoclea, etc. For all of above system brings an error - unmet dependencies. Another search and -f install, dist-upgrade, purge remove unattended-upgrades, remove generic... and many more, all are unsuccessful.

I am either unable to update, install or uninstall because of low root space or unmet dependencies. 
Typical error message looks like this...

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies.
>    linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-3.13.0-139-generic but it is not going to be installed
>    linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-extra-3.13.0-139-generic but it is not going to be installed
>    linux-signed-image-3.13.0-139-generic : Depends: linux-image-extra-3.13.0-139-generic (= 3.13.0-139.188) but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

or

> The following packages have unmet dependencies.
>    linux-signed-generic : Depends: linux-headers-generic (= 3.13.0.139.148) but it is not installable
>    linux-signed-image-3.13.0-139-generic : Depends: linux-image-extra-3.13.0-139-generic (= 3.13.0-139.188) but it is not installable
>   E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Hours of searching brought me here, sorry and please help.

Just for reference;

> df -Th

-gives

> Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
>
> udev           devtmpfs  3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
>
> tmpfs          tmpfs     792M  1.2M  791M   1% /run
>
> /dev/sda6      ext4       19G   17G  716M  96% /
>
> none           tmpfs     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
>
> none           tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
>
> none           tmpfs     3.9G   16M  3.9G   1% /run/shm
>
> none           tmpfs     100M   44K  100M   1% /run/user
>
> /dev/sda8      ext4      657G  7.8G  616G   2% /home
>
> /dev/sda2      vfat      256M  116M  141M  46% /boot/efi

-

> sudo du -hs /*

-gives

> 9.9M   /bin
>
> 1.4G   /boot
>
> 4.0K   /cdrom
>
> 4.0K   /dev
>
> 23M    /etc
>
> 7.7G   /home
>
> 0  /initrd.img
>
> 0  /initrd.img.old
>
> 6.8G   /lib
>
> 3.5M   /lib32
>
> 4.0K   /lib64
>
> 16K    /lost+found
>
> 8.0K   /media
>
> 4.0K   /mnt
>
> du: cannot access ‘/proc/4560/task/4560/fd/4’: No such file or directory
>
> du: cannot access ‘/proc/4560/task/4560/fdinfo/4’: No such file or 
>   directory
>
> du: cannot access ‘/proc/4560/fd/4’: No such file or directory
>
> du: cannot access ‘/proc/4560/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
>
> 0  /proc
>
> 76K    /root
>
> du: cannot access ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
>
> 1.3M   /run
>
> 12M    /sbin
>
> 4.0K   /srv
>
> 0  /sys
>
> 44K    /tmp
>
> 8.0G   /usr
>
> 682M   /var
>
> 0  /vmlinuz
>
> 0  /vmlinuz.old

Answer (score 0):

Since / is 96% full, you need to look at why the numbers of the folders on / don't add up to the 17G claimed to be in use. One thing I have seen in the past is that when a partition is not mounted (e.g. /home) AND you write anything to the folder /home, it gets written to the partition where the parent is (/) Then when you mount the partition, the files that were in the folder take up space but are not seen.

So if /dev/sda8 was not mounted at some point in time and you copied files into /home, they now occupy space in the root partition. Then when /dev/sda8 is mounted to /home, all those files are invisible. Since /home is the only directory on your system that is a separate partition mounted under root, you might try booting a Live-CD system, making sure that /dev/sda8 is not mounted and then see if you have any file/directories in the /dev/sda6 paritition's directory which will not be he / directory to the Live-CD system but will be /media/[unique id] and be your regular system's root directory. In that directory will be a directory "home". It should have nothing in it as "home" is a separate partition.

At that point you might also do an fsck of that partition to see if it is consistent.